# $\int_L^\infty \exp(- t - y/t) \, dt = \text{?}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory, special-functions

Let $y>0$, $L>0$. Has the (special?) function given by
$$f(y,L) = \int_{L}^\infty e^{- t - y/t} \, dt$$
been studied? Are there precise, simple bounds?

---

Let me try to attempt to reinvent the wheel, briefly:

The integrand clearly takes its maximum when $t = \sqrt{y}$, and so we have two kinds of behavior depending on whether $L\leq \sqrt{y}$ or $L>\sqrt{y}$. If $L\leq \sqrt{y}$, then the main contribution is that of $t\sim \sqrt{y}$: around there, $-t-y/t = -2\sqrt{y} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} (t - \sqrt{y})^2 + \dotsc$, and so the main term of $f(y,L)$ should be $$e^{-2 \sqrt{y}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{y}}} \, dx = \sqrt{\pi} y^{1/4}  e^{-2 \sqrt{y}}.$$ If $L>\sqrt{y}$, then the main contribution comes from $t$ close to $L$. Around there, $$-t-y/t = -L - \frac{y}{L} - \left(1-\frac{y}{L^2}\right) (t-L) + \dotsb,$$ and so the main term of $f(y,L)$ should be
$$e^{-L-\frac{y}{L}} \int_0^\infty e^{-\left(1-\frac{y}{L^2}\right) x} dx = 
\frac{e^{-L - \frac{y}{L}}}{1 - \frac{y}{L^2}}.$$

---

Motivation: this integral comes up in smoothed variants of the prime number theorem.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: You seem to have asked three questions in this post. MO's guidelines say ["avoid trying to answer questions which ... request answers to multiple questions"](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer). Also, concerning "precise, simple bounds", you seem to have done much of the work. So, it is unclear what kind of answer you want to see.

Comment: Well, I've given the main terms, not bounds. Plus, I'd like to know whether this has been studied (it's all one question, in the end).

Comment: Which regime are you interested in? Or you need bounds working for all $y, L$?

Comment: Let me see whether the bounds given below for $L\leq \sqrt{y}$ suffice for my purposes. The bounds for $L>\sqrt{y}$ are nice and simple, but they blow up when one gets to close to $\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: @HAHelfgott : Do you think it is possible now for you to select the best (most helpful) answer?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Well, I think yours was clearly the most helpful answer; what I've tried to do is synthesize it and other answers and complete them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the previous, already very long [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/448283/36721), upper and lower bounds on $f(y,L)$ were provided, which were asymptotically exact as $y\to\infty$ uniformly over all values of $r:=L/\sqrt y$ bounded away from $1$. However, those bounds were not good for $r$ near $1$ (unless $x:=\sqrt y$ is very large).

So, here we will give an upper bound on $f(y,L)$ that is very good for all $r>0$ even for very moderate values of $x$.

As in the previous answer, we have
\begin{equation*}
    f(y,L)=\sqrt y\,g(L/\sqrt y,\sqrt y), 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    g(r,x)=\tfrac12\,I(r,x)+J(r,x), \tag{100}\label{100}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
I(r,x)=\int_{t_r}^\infty e^{-xt}(F(t)+1)\,dt
=e^{-2x}\int_{z_r}^\infty e^{-xz}G(z)\,dz,     
\tag{200}\label{200}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    J(r,x)=\int_2^{t_r} e^{-xt}F(t)\,dt=e^{-2x}\int_0^{z_r} e^{-xz}G(z)\,dz, \tag{300}\label{300}
\end{equation*}
$t_r=r+1/r$, $z_r:=t_r-2=r+1/r-2=(1/\sqrt r-\sqrt r)^2$,
$F(t)=\dfrac t{\sqrt{t^2-4}}$,
\begin{equation*}
    G(z)=\frac1{\sqrt z}\frac{2+z}{\sqrt{4+z}}<\frac{1+3z/8}{\sqrt z}.  \tag{400}\label{400}
\end{equation*}

So, it is enough to bound $g(r,x)$. Replacing $G(z)$ in \eqref{300} by its upper bound $\frac{1+3z/8}{\sqrt z}$ from \eqref{400}, we get an upper bound on $J(r,x)$:
\begin{equation*}
    J(r,x)\le J_U(r,x):=e^{-2x}\int_0^{z_r} e^{-xz}\frac{1+3z/8}{\sqrt z}\,dz \\ 
    =e^{-x(2+z_r)}\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (16 x+3) e^{x z_r} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{x z_r}\right)
    -6 \sqrt{x z_r}}{16 x^{3/2}}. \tag{500}\label{500}
\end{equation*}

Next, $H(z):=G(z)\sqrt z$ is concave in $z>0$. So, replacing $G(z)$ in \eqref{200} by its upper bound
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{H(z_r)+H'(z_r)(z-z_r)}{\sqrt z}, 
\end{equation*}
we get an upper bound on $I(r,x)$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    & I(r,x)\le I_U(r,x) \\ 
    &:= \frac{e^{-x (z_r+2)}}{4 (x(z_r+4))^{3/2}} \\ 
    &\times
    \Big[\left(\sqrt{\pi } e^{x z_r}
   \left(2 x \left(z_r^2+6
   z_r+16\right)+z_r+6\right)
   \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{x z_r}\right)\right) \\ 
  & \quad+2 \left(\sqrt{x z_r^3}+2 z_r \sqrt{x (z_r+4)}+6 \sqrt{x z_r}+8 \sqrt{x(z_r+4)}\right)\Big]
. 
\end{aligned}
\tag{600}\label{600}
\end{equation*}

So, by \eqref{100},
\begin{equation*}
    g(r,x)\le g_U(r,x):=\tfrac12\,I_U(r,x)+J_U(r,x),  
\end{equation*}
with $I_U(r,x)$ and $J_U(r,x)$ as in \eqref{600} and \eqref{500}.

---

Shown below are parts of the graphs $\Big\{\Big(r,\dfrac{g_U(r,x)}{g(r,x)}\Big)\colon r>0\Big\}$ for $x=2,10,50$. We see that the ratio $\dfrac{g_U(r,x)}{g(r,x)}$ of the upper bound $g_U(r,x)$ on $g(r,x)$ to $g(r,x)$ is just slightly greater than $1$ even for $x=2$.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Using the substitution $t=s\sqrt y$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    f(y,L)=\sqrt y\,g(L/\sqrt y,\sqrt y), 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    g(r,x):=\int_r^\infty e^{-x(s+1/s)}\,ds, 
\end{equation*}
$r>0$, $x>0$.
So, it is enough to study $g(r,x)$. Using now the substitution $t=s+1/s$ and letting
\begin{equation*}
    F(t):=\frac t{\sqrt{t^2-4}}\quad\text{and}\quad t_r:=r+1/r,  
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{equation*}
    g(r,x)=
\left\{ 
\begin{alignedat}{2}
    &\frac12\,\int_{t_r}^\infty e^{-xt}(F(t)+1)\,dt &&\quad\text{if }r\ge1, \\ 
    &\frac12\,\int_2^{t_r} e^{-xt}(F(t)-1)\,dt && \\ 
    &+\frac12\,\int_2^\infty e^{-xt}(F(t)+1)\,dt
     &&\quad\text{if }r\in(0,1].   
\end{alignedat}
\right. 
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}

Integrating by parts twice, we get
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
I(r,x)&:=\int_{t_r}^\infty e^{-xt}(F(t)+1)\,dt  \\ 
    &=\frac1x\,e^{-xt_r}(F(t_r)+1)+\frac1x\,\int_{t_r}^\infty e^{-xt}F'(t)\,dt  \\    
    &=\frac1x\,e^{-xt_r}\Big(F(t_r)+1+\frac1x\,F'(t_r)\Big) \\ 
&+\frac1{x^2}\,\int_{t_r}^\infty e^{-xt}F''(t)\,dt.     
\end{aligned} 
\tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
Note now that for $t>2$
\begin{equation*}
    F'(t)=-\frac{4}{\left(t^2-4\right)^{3/2}}<0,\quad F''(t)=\frac{12 t}{\left(t^2-4\right)^{5/2}}>0. 
\end{equation*}
So, from our integration by parts we get
\begin{equation*}
    2l(r,x)<I(r,x)<2u(r,x)
\end{equation*}
$r\ge1$ and $x>0$, where
\begin{equation*}
    u(r,x):=\frac1{2x}\,e^{-xt_r}(F(t_r)+1)=\frac1{2x}e^{-x(r+1/r)}\frac{2r^2}{r^2-1}   
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    l(r,x):=\frac1{2x}\,e^{-xt_r}\Big(F(t_r)+1+\frac1x\,F'(t_r)\Big) \\ 
=   \frac1{2x}e^{-x(r+1/r)}\Big(\frac{2r^2}{r^2-1}-\frac1x\frac{4 r^3}{\left(r^2-1\right)^3}\Big).  
\end{equation*}
So, by \eqref{10},
\begin{equation*}
    l(r,x)<g(r,x)<u(r,x) \quad\text{for }r>1. 
\end{equation*}

In the original version of the OP, particular interest was expressed in large values of $y$ and $L$, so that $x=\sqrt y$ is large. Accordingly, we have $l(r,x)\sim u(r,x)$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    l(r,x)\sim g(r,x)\sim u(u,x)
\end{equation*}
as $x\to\infty$ uniformly in $r\ge r_0$, for each real $r_0>1$, which means that the upper and lower bounds $u(r,x)$ and $l(r,x)$ on $g(r,x)$ are asymptotically exact for such $r$ and $x$.

---

Consider now the case $r\in(0,1)$. Then, by \eqref{10},
\begin{equation*}
    2g(r,x)=I(r,x)+2J(r,x), 
\end{equation*}
where $I(r,x)$ is as in \eqref{20} and
\begin{equation*}
    J(r,x):=\int_2^{t_r} e^{-xt}F(t)\,dt=e^{-2x}\int_0^{z_r} e^{-xz}G(z)\,dz, \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
where $z_r:=t_r-2=r+1/r-2=(1/\sqrt r-\sqrt r)^2$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \frac1{\sqrt z}<G(z):=\frac1{\sqrt z}\frac{2+z}{\sqrt{4+z}}<\frac{1+3z/8}{\sqrt z} \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}
for real $z>0$.

Using these lower and upper bounds on $G(z)$ together with \eqref{30}, we get
\begin{equation*}
    l_1(r,x)<J(r,x)<u_1(r,x), 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    l_1(r,x):=e^{-2x}\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{x
   z_r}\right)}{\sqrt{x}},
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    u_1(r,x):=l_1(r,x)
    +e^{-2x}\frac{3\sqrt{\pi }\, \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{x
   z_r}\right)}{16x^{3/2}}
   -e^{-2x}\frac{3 \sqrt{z_r} e^{-x
   z_r}}{8x}. 
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    L(r,x):=l(r,x)+l_1(r,x)<g(r,x)<U(r,x):=u(r,x)+u_1(r,x) \quad\text{for }r\in(0,1)  
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    L(r,x)\sim g(r,x)\sim U(u,x)
\end{equation*}
as $x\to\infty$ uniformly in $r\in(0,r_0]$, for each real $r_0\in(0,1)$, which means that the upper and lower bounds $U(r,x)$ and $L(r,x)$ on $g(r,x)$ are asymptotically exact for such $r$ and $x$.

---

Using the inequality $G(z)<1+1/\sqrt z$ instead of the second inequality in \eqref{40}, we get
\begin{equation*}
    J(r,x)<\tilde u_1(r,x):=l_1(r,x)+ e^{-2x}\frac{1-e^{-xz_r}}x.
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    L(r,x)<g(r,x)<\tilde U(r,x):=u(r,x)+\tilde u_1(r,x) \quad\text{for }r\in(0,1)  
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    L(r,x)\sim g(r,x)\sim \tilde U(u,x)
\end{equation*}
as $x\to\infty$ uniformly in $r\in(0,r_0]$, for each real $r_0\in(0,1)$, which means that the upper and lower bounds $\tilde U(r,x)$ and $L(r,x)$ on $g(r,x)$ are asymptotically exact for such $r$ and $x$.
The upper bound $\tilde U(r,x)$ on $g(r,x)$ is simpler than $U(r,x)$, but not as accurate for large $x$.

Comment: I'm especially interested in the case $r\in (0,1)$ - one can give a very simple upper bound in the case $r>1$, as in my brief self-answer.

Comment: @HAHelfgott : I think the twice repeated integration by parts as in this answer will work for $r\in(0,1)$ as well -- because $F'<0$ and $F''>0$ on the entire interval $(2,\infty)$. I just don't have time to do this in detail at this point. (Also, I think your upper bound for $L>\sqrt y$ is essentially the same as my upper for $r>1$.)

Comment: Right, I'm wondering why small and large $r$ are equally from your perspective, since they aren't from mine.

Comment: @HAHelfgott : You were right, the case $r\in(0,1)$ is different, because here $t$ may take values close to the point $2$ of singularity of $F$. Now this case is done as well, anyhow.

Comment: @HAHelfgott : Do you have a further response to this and other answers?

Comment: I think your second answer is particularly nice. Let me adapt to $r\geq 1$ (which is the simpler case) and possibly simplify it a little - I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 4):

References to the study of these functions which are frequently used in hydrological models. No precise bounds in the following papers but at least they give a starting point.

- Harris (2008) ["Incomplete Bessel, generalized incomplete gamma,
  or leaky aquifer functions"](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81935301.pdf). First became aware of this in [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4237209/471884)
- Chaudhry et al (1996) ["Asymptotics and closed form of a generalized incomplete gamma function"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042795000186)
- Pogány et al (2015) ["Incomplete Kratzel Function Model of Leaky Aquifer and Alike Functions"](http://real.mtak.hu/27188/1/Model%20of%20leaky%20aquifer%20and%20alike%20functions.pdf)

$L=0$ leads to Krätzel functions, $L=1$ is called leaky aquifer functions; otherwise they are just called "generalised incomplete gamma function" with $\alpha=1$.

Comment: PS I will be posting only on MO (due to its special status in the network) but will not moderate anything as part of the strike

Answer (score 2):

I'll continue here since there is already too much answer in my question, apparently.

It is easy to give a good upper bound in the case $L> \sqrt{y}$: since $(-t-y/t)' = -1 + y/t^2 \leq -1 + y/L^2 < 0$ for *all* $t\geq L$, we know that $$-t-y/t\leq - L - \frac{y}{L} - \left(1 - \frac{y}{L^2}\right) (t-L),$$ and so
the main term in the question is actually an upper bound:
$$e^{-L-\frac{y}{L}} \int_0^\infty e^{-\left(1-\frac{y}{L^2}\right) x} dx \leq 
\frac{e^{-L - \frac{y}{L}}}{1 - \frac{y}{L^2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

When $L=0$ you get an integral representation of the modified Bessel function $K_{-1}(z) = K_{1}(z)$ [[DLMF §10.32 (10)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E10)],
$$
  f(y,0) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t-y/t} dt = 2 \sqrt{y} K_1(2\sqrt{y}) .
$$
The integrand is everywhere positive, so $f(y,L)$ is monotone decreasing in $L$. At $t=0$, the integrand is flat (has a vanishing Taylor series), so near $L=0$, any corrections to the simple bound $f(y,L) \le f(y,0)$ will be exponential in $1/L$. The bound is also uniform in $L$, but not very good for large $L$. For large $L$, as already noted, since $e^{-t-y/t} \le e^{-t}$ everywhere, we get another uniform bound $f(y,L) \le e^{-L}$. Putting them together, we find
$$
  f(y,L) \le \min\{ 2\sqrt{y} K_1(2\sqrt{y}) , e^{-L} \} .
$$
The curve where the two estimates meet is of course along
$$
  L = -\ln\left[2\sqrt{y} K_1(2\sqrt{y})\right]
  \sim \begin{cases}
    (1-2 \gamma - \ln y) y + O(y^2\ln y) & \text{as } y\to 0 , \\
    2\sqrt{y} - \frac{1}{4} \ln y - \ln\sqrt{\pi} + O(1/\sqrt{y}) & \text{as } y \to \infty ,
  \end{cases}
$$
which uses asymptotic expansions of $K_1(z)$ at $z=0$ [[DLMF §10.31 (1)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.31.E1)] and $z=\infty$ [[DLMF §10.40 (2)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.E2)].

If more precise estimates are required, probably some of the above steps could be refined.

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize and condense what @IosefPinelis has said.

We are to estimate $$f(y,L) = \int_L^\infty e^{-t-y/t} dt = \sqrt{y} g(L/\sqrt{y},\sqrt{y}),$$
where $g(r,x)=\int_r^\infty e^{-x(s+1/s)} ds.$ By a substitution of variables $t = r+1/r$,
$$g(r,x) = \frac{1}{2} I(r,x) + \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if $r\geq 1$,}\\ J(r,x)& \text{if $0<r<1$,}\end{cases}$$
where $$I(r,x) = \int_{r+1/r}^\infty e^{-x t} (F(t)+1) dt,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
J(r,x) = \int_2^{r+1/r} e^{-x t} F(t) dt$$ and $F(t) = \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-4}}$. (We are using the fact that $F(t)$ is an odd function.) Letting $t = u+2$, we see that
$$I(r,x) = e^{-2 x} \int_{u_r}^\infty e^{-x u} (G(u)+1) du,
\;\;\;\;J(r,x)= e^{-2 x}\int_0^{u_r} e^{-x u} G(u) du,$$
where $G(u) = F(u+2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \frac{1+u/2}{\sqrt{1+u/4}}$ for $u\geq 0$ and $u_r = r+1/r-2$.

We can give different upper bounds on $G(u)$. @IosefPinelis used the bound $H(u)\leq H(u_r) + (u-u_r) H'(u_r)$ for $H(u) = \sqrt{u} G(u)$ and $u\geq u_r$ (by concavity of $H(u)$) and, in particular, $H(u)\leq 1 + \frac{3 u}{8}$ for $u\geq 0$; he showed how to obtain bounds on $g(r,x)$ in consequence. He also mentioned once a bound that is useful, if crude, viz., given by $G(u)\leq 1/\sqrt{u} + 1$ for $u\geq 0$.  (It can overestimate $G(u)$ by up to almost 50%, and $1+G(u)$ by up to almost 30%.) Let us work with this crude bound in detail.

We obtain
$$\begin{aligned}I(r,x)&\leq e^{-2 x}\int_{u_r}^\infty e^{-x u} \left(2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\right) du = \frac{e^{-x (u_r+2)}}{x} + \frac{e^{-2 x}}{\sqrt{x}} \int_{x u_r}^\infty e^{-v} \frac{dv}{\sqrt{v}} \\ &= \frac{e^{-x (r+1/r)}}{x} + \frac{2 e^{-2 x}}{\sqrt{x}} \int_{\sqrt{xu_r}}^\infty e^{-t^2} dt
= \left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} M(\sqrt{x u_r}) \right)e^{-x (r+1/r)},\end{aligned}$$
where $M(x)$ is Mills' ratio $M(x) = e^{x^2} \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2} dt$.

The special case $u_r=0$ in that, according to an answer by @openletter.mousetail.nl, it leads to a fancy special function called a leaky aquifer function (too fancy for the NIST handbook, apparently). Of course we can just use the bound above.

Just as above,
$$\begin{aligned}J(r,x) &= e^{-2 x} \int_0^{u_r} e^{-x u} \left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\right) du = e^{-2 x} \frac{1-e^{-x u_r}}{x} + \frac{e^{-2 x}}{\sqrt{x}} \int_0^{x u_r} e^{-v} \frac{dv}{\sqrt{v}} \\ &= \frac{e^{-2 x}-e^{-x (r+1/r)}}{x} + \frac{2 e^{-2 x}}{\sqrt{x}} \int_0^{\sqrt{xu_r}} e^{-t^2} dt
\leq \frac{e^{-2 x}}{x} + \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}} e^{-2 x} -
\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} M(\sqrt{x u_r}) \right) e^{-x (r+1/r)}.\end{aligned}$$

We conclude that
$$g(r,x) = \begin{cases}\left(\frac{1}{2 x} + \frac{M(\sqrt{x u_r})}{\sqrt{x}}\right) e^{-x (r+1/r)} &\text{if $r\geq 1$,}\\ \left(\frac{1}{x} + \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}}\right) e^{-2 x} - \left(\frac{1}{2 x} + \frac{M(\sqrt{x u_r})}{\sqrt{x}}\right) e^{-x (r+1/r)}& \text{if $0<r<1$,}
\end{cases}$$

For $x\geq 0$, $\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}} < M(x)\leq \frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+(4/\pi)}}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{\pi} x + 2} \leq M(x)<\frac{1}{x+1}$ (NIST Handbook, section 7.8).

Of course we also have the upper bound $$g(r,x)\leq g(0,x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x (s+1/s)} ds = 2 K_1(2 x),$$ where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind. The leading-order terms of $2 K_1(2 x)$ are $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}} e^{-2 x} \left(1 + \frac{3}{8 x} + \dotsc\right)$; in fact, $2 K_1(2 x)\leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}} e^{-2 x} \left(1 + \frac{3}{8 x}\right)$ (see NIST Handbook, 10.40(ii); thanks to a Facebook friend for this reference). As @igorKhavkine points out, this is very good for $r$ close to $0$ (or $r\in (0,1)$ and $x$ large).

---

Let's talk about an application, in part so that we can see what happens for some specific range of values of the parameters.

Assume we have a Riemann-Hypothesis check up to height $H$, i.e., assume we know that $\Re s = 1/2$ for every non-trivial zero $s$ of $\zeta(s)$ with $|\Im s|\leq H$. (This is currently known rigorously for $H \leq 3\cdot 10^{12}$ (Platt-Trudgian, 2021).) Assume as well that we have a zero-free region of classical form: for every non-trivial zero $s$ of $\zeta(s)$, $\Re s \leq 1 - \frac{1}{C \Im s}$. (This is known with $C = 5.573\dotsc$ (Mossinghoff-Trudgian, 2015); there's a very recent improvement with $C = 5.558\dotsc$ (Mossinghoff-Trudgian-Yang).)

The problem is to estimate sums of the form
$$\sum_{n\leq X} \Lambda(n) \log \frac{X}{n},$$
where $\Lambda(n)$ is the von Mangoldt function. (Here $\log \frac{X}{n}$ is a very natural smoothing that often pops up of its own accord.) By standard Mellin-transform magic and the assumptions above, this problem reduces to estimating $$I = \int_H^\infty X^{1 - \frac{1}{C \log \tau}} \frac{dt}{t^2}.$$
(I am not forgetting a factor of $\log t$ here; there are good explicit density results that enable us to do this (Kadiri 2013, in the style of Bohr-Landau) and even more (Kadiri-Lumley-Ng 2018).)

By the substitution $\tau = e^t$,
$$I = \int_{\log H}^\infty X^{1 - \frac{1}{C t}} \frac{dt}{e^t}
= X \int_{\log H}^\infty e^{- t- \frac{(\log X)/C}{t}} dt.$$
In other words, $I = X f(y,L)$ with $y = \frac{\log X}{C}$, $L = \log H$, and so $$I = x g\left(\frac{\log H}{x},x\right)\cdot X$$
with $x = \sqrt{\frac{\log X}{C}}$.

We can assume $X\geq 10^{19}$ or so (as estimates for sums with smaller $X$ can be obtained by brute force). Hence, we can assume
$$x\geq \sqrt{\frac{\log 10^{19}}{C}} = 2.8018\dotsc.$$

We also get that $r \leq \frac{\log H}{x} \leq 10.254$, but that is useful mainly in that it tells us that $u_r$ is large when $x$ is not much, much larger than $10^{19}$. That does tell us that, in that critical case, the bound $G(u)\leq 1 + 1/\sqrt{u}$ we have used is actually pretty good.

What is more interesting is the phase transition that happens at $r=1$, i.e., $x = \exp(C (\log H)^2) \approx \exp(4600)$. For considerably lower $x$, the zero-free region doesn't matter that much, whereas for higher $x$ gains come mainly from the zero-free region. (This should be completely unsurprising to people in the field; estimates for unsmoothed sums $\sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda(n)$ also have this "phase transition".)

Answer (score 0):

For L=0:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-t-y/t)dt=\fbox{$2\sqrt{y}K_1\left(2\sqrt{y}\right)\text{if}\Re(y)>0$}$

$K_{1}$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind!

There is no closed form for $L>0$ which is the question!

This function under the integral looks like being designed for calculations with the Laplace transformation.

There is a general rule for Laplace transforms in the kind of $\exp(a t)f(t)$. That is of course what You gave.

So the Laplace transform with respect to $y,s$ of

$\exp(-t)\exp(-y/t)$

is

$\frac{e^{-t}}{s+\frac{1}{t}}$

You may now in the space Laplace transformed do Your integration the easy way and transform Laplace inverse afterwards.

The integration of the function under the integral sign in Laplace space is comfortably done:

$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{e^{\frac{1}{s}} \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{L
   s+1}{s}\right)+e^{-L} s}{s^2},\Im\left(\frac{1}{s}\right) \Re(L)\neq \Im(L)
   \Re\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)\lor L+\frac{1}{s}>0\lor L\notin \mathbb{R}\lor
   L+\frac{1}{s}\notin \mathbb{R}\right]$

This is as expected dependent on $L$!

The first part of the inverse Laplace transform is only $\exp(-L)$. The second one is rather complicated.

The inverse is

very complicated to calculated. To get an $f(y,L)$ it is hard work to be done. This suit for an Laplace transformed redefinition that can be evaluated for given $L$ and $y$. I expected this to be solvable with Mathematica full edition in an explicit form and exact with the condition that is calculated for the Laplace transformed representation.

Not doing the integral on the Laplace transformed representation hinders the exact solution.

So two things to understand. First, how to do Laplace transforms and their inverse. Second, how to understand that the Laplace transformation back and force is allowed with the shown use of the integration that is already given. That is a far way through Laplace transform theory. But since both are about infinity integration, the methods are similar. The finite integrals have to converge towards the infinite for all finite values. And confirm the acquired restrictions up to this point are not much more or harder than the given ones.

There is a logarithmic - polynomial expansion for $ExpIntegralEi$, $Ei$. For this the polynomial part are easy to be inverse Laplace transformed and give an $(y,L)$-dependent result. The logarithmic part is very hard to inverse Laplace transform.

For simpler Taylor series the inverse Laplace transform is straight forward, but the convergence is not safe anymore.

$f(y,L)=InverseLaplaceTransform[\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{e^{\frac{1}{s}} \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{L
   s+1}{s}\right)+e^{-L} s}{s^2},\Im\left(\frac{1}{s}\right) \Re(L)\neq \Im(L)
   \Re\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)\lor L+\frac{1}{s}>0\lor L\notin \mathbb{R}\lor
   L+\frac{1}{s}\notin \mathbb{R}\right],s,y]$

for $L>0$. This can be evaluated numerical for a given $L$.

The logarithmic part is present too in the modified Bessel function of the second kind, if developed. So the inverse Laplace transform may be dropped and the untransformed function discussed for conveniences.

A solution is easily written for $y=0$ that is $\exp(-L)$. A similar term appears in the Laplace transform.